# WiX error build target

Tags: msbuild, wix, installation

I'm trying to create my MSI setup with WiX and MSBuild command which deploy my img.png into a repertory and i have this error :

> "MSB4019: project imported "C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v[[Version.M ajor]].x\Wix.targets" was not
>   found. " Make sure that path of  declaration are correct

In this line :

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetPath)" />
```

Here my 2 files (test.wixproj and test.wxs) :

test.wixproj

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
                <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
                <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
                <ProductVersion>3.0</ProductVersion>
                <ProjectGuid>{}</ProjectGuid>
                <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
                <OutputName>WixProject1</OutputName>
                <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
                <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v[[Version.Major]].x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
                <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
                <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
                <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
                <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
                <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
                <Compile Include="C:\testW2.wxs" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
    </Project>
```

test.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="" Version="1.0.0.0" Language="1033" Name="My Application Name" Manufacturer="My Manufacturer Name">
        <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Application test"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>


        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
            <Component Id="myimg" Guid="">
                <File Id="myimg" Source="C:\img.png" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>

        </DirectoryRef>


        <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="myimg" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

I don't unstandand where is the problem and i don't find an easy tutorial on WiX without VisualStudio.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your project file:

1. The `<WixTargetPath ...>` line [[MajorVersion]] should be replaced with '3',
2. The `<Compile...>` line should to refer to the correct file 'Test.wxs'.

Try this project file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
            <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
            <ProductVersion>3.0</ProductVersion>
            <ProjectGuid>{}</ProjectGuid>
            <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
            <OutputName>WixProject1</OutputName>
            <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
            <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
            <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
            <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
            <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
            <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
            <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Include="test.wxs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
</Project>
```

You also need to make sure **test.wxs** has a GUID in the `UpgradeCode` attribute.

Comment: Oh thank you, it works. But do you know how to change the repertory to install, here is C\Programmfiles\myapplication ? I would C:\Documents and settings\toto\Desktop for example. Or if i want install 2 files into a folder and 2 others files in another folder ?

Comment: The WIX toolset has good documentation on this topic http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html.  If that does not help try searching Stack Overflow for existing questions on WIX directories.  If after this you can't find your answer, then ask a new question.  Note: A comment is not the correct place for new questions.

Comment: Yes excuse me, i'm currently reading the documentation and stack overflow questions. Thanks for all.